# Audio-Streaming IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0xFFFFFFF6

Tags: android

Android 2.3 Mediaplayer can't play none of [those audiostreams](http://radio02-cn03.akadostream.ru:8114/) resulting in `W/System.err(19610): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0xFFFFFFF6`. However, the same stream works fine on Android 4.0.

Is there anything I can provide the app with to make it work on Android 2.3 platform ?

Thanks.

Some code that I use:

```
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(mOnErrorListener);

    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mOnPreparedListener);
    mPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(mOnBufferingUpdateListener);
    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(
                this,
                Uri.parse("http://radio02-cn03.akadostream.ru:8114/detifm192.mp3"));
        mPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**UPD**
I'm able to play "http://radio02-cn03.akadostream.ru:8114/detifm192.mp3" with MoboPlayer - any suggestions how they do it ? It plays after message "trying soft decoding mode"

Answer (score 0):

Check there encoding. It seems that hardware decoding is failing.

Comment: What does hardware decoding mean ? Isn't it all software driven - I mean this mp3 is a stream of bytes - how it's playback is dependent on hardware ? And if you're - what are my options - are there any free software decoding libs I could incorporate ?

Comment: Hardware decoding is the same as software decoding but happens on the chipset. It's much more efficient. Anyway, if the file encoding is really mp3 (not just an extension), then it is not an encoding issue. So, check if the file encoding is really an mp3.

Comment: it turned out that it's a live stream and it's I guess isn't supported before Android 3.0. I've tried Vitamio -but don't want to make customers install third library - any suggestions ?

Comment: Streaming is supported down to version 2.3. So, it should work. Did you try another mp3 file from another source? .. just for sanity.

Comment: yeah, and some of them work, but how can I define actual parameters for a stream that can be played? From my observation bitrate and sample rate are the only things that differ. Here're two examples [city beat radio(can be played)](http://imgur.com/Pj75s) , [the one that can't be played](http://imgur.com/fSWrA)